# Descargar archivo sin redirigir página usando "force_download('/path/to/photo.jpg', NULL);"

Tags: codeigniter

Tengo una función al cual se le pasa el nombre de un archivo por el método "POST", pero necesito que al ser ejecutada la descarga no se me redirija a la visualización del archivo en el navegador: quiero que se me descargue el archivo, pero que no me cambia de página

```
public function descargar_archivo()
    {
            $archivo=$this->input->post("archivo");
            //force_download('/path/to/photo.jpg', NULL);
            force_download($archivo, NULL);
    }
```

Alguien sabe cómo hacer esto?. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Debe de funcionar de la siguiente manera, primero cargas el `helper` de `download`:

```
$this->load->helper('download');
```

Obtienes el nombre y dirección del archivo:

```
$path = file_get_contents(base_url($archivo));
```

Creas el nuevo nombre para el archivo (si lo requiere):

```
$name = "nuevo.pdf";
```

Procedes a la descarga directa:

```
force_download($name, $path);
```

A mi me funciona perfectamente, no debería de generar problema alguno.